# How can I change Ctrl+E key binding to F12

Tags: sublimetext3, abbreviation, emmet

I have installed Sublime text3 today. also I installed emmet plugin.

Now plugin abbreviation command works by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> button.

I want to change it to <kbd>F12</kbd>, I mean I want whenever I press <kbd>F12</kbd> it works same as pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> buttons

I have searched a lot and tried a lot of ways, but I could not do that.

Please guide me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Open the sublime text console and enter `sublime.log_commands(True)`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> as if you were expanding an abbreviation. The ST console, will display the command and arguments to use in your key binding. The key binding will have the form

```
{"keys": ["f12"], "command": <command listed in the console>, "args": <object containing args listed if applicable.>}
```

**Edit**

```
[
    {
        "keys": [
            "f12"
        ], 
        "args": {
            "action": "expand_abbreviation"
        }, 
        "command": "run_emmet_action", 
        "context": [
            {
                "key": "emmet_action_enabled.expand_abbreviation"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Log command works but I didn't find if want to change the ctrl+e to another command such as ctrl+enter or anything else, what file should I edit it. I found that F12 key is used for "go to definition" command. so I decided to use ctrl+enter instead of F12 for "ctrl+e" action command. Now can you guide me more.

Comment: Go to `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User` and enter the content of my edit. If you already have key binding entries, remove the square brackets. These files are JSON, so just add a comma where necessary.